# Communication between 2 phones with CloudDB using Listpickers in App inventor2

Tags: app-inventor

i'm working on an application that i developped in App Inventor2. It contains 2 listpickers and i want to establish communication between two cell phones with CloudDB to send selected index from a phone to another.
When I connect the cell phones to the app, I receive the error: List index smaller than 1. Select list item: Attempt to get item number 0, of the list (44 - P...). The minimum valid item number is 1.
Thanks in advance for your advices.

Comment: Provide any code?

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko thank you for your respond. I just don't know how to attach the file (.aia) ? Please find here screens of my code : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/mitappinventortest/specific-programming-issue/phonetablet-with-the-wifi/home-network/mit-appinventor-2/ztSFwta_QDU